# Polygons: why are three and four different from other "sidegons"

Tags: terminology

A few past Questions almost get to my query but even this about "name-gons" doesn't quite do it. Please don't even trouble to read on unless you're interested in what might seem totally trivial…

Why are three- and four-sided figures not called "trigons" and "tetragons", or indeed any-kind of "…gon"?

Above seven, it would be very odd to deviate from the standard list of names for polygons: octa…, nona…, deca… etc.

For six and seven it might not seem so strange to see "sex…" and "sept…" instead of "hex…" and "heptagon" but those are still "sidegons".

Three and four seem to be exceptions and I'm wondering whether there's any rule for that, linguistic or mathematical, or it's just traditional.

Is "trigon" seriously used for "triangle", except broadly as in "trigonometry"?

Is "tetragon" really used for "quadrangle"? Quad itself seems to be the special preserve of academia and even "rectangle" is often usurped by "oblong" or "square".

This might well seem wholly pointless yet on a different level, three and four-sided figures, when they're equilateral, are physically different.

That is, squares and equilateral triangles are the only shapes any old bodger can construct with a single measurement and almost no skill; unexpectedly useful in many practical applications - and that's apart from the triangle being the only rigid shape. Is that wholly irrelevant, or could it somehow bleed across into the nomenclature?

Comment: You can add dictionary definitions for _tetragon_ and _trigon_, together with caveats ('archaic' for the latter).

Comment: If you can construct all three sides of an equilateral triangle from scratch with your single measurement, you can certainly make another such  triangle on one of those sides. Keep repeating that around a common point and you have a hexagon.

Comment: @DjinTonic Quite… which is one reason hexagons tessellate as well as triangles or squares and nothing else but specially selected oblongs/quadrangles/rectangles

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin There are [irregular pentagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation) that can tile the plane

Comment: @DjinTonic That might be but here, it has no relevance.

Comment: Note that *quadrangle* has a particular meaning which differs from *quadrilateral.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks and yes, but not usefully. Did you notice where I Posted "Quad itself seems to be the special preserve of academia…"?

Answer (score 1):

According to the OED's citations, *square* was first used 1300-1400; *triangle* 1398;  *quadrangle* 1398; *rectangle* 1560;

then  *hexagon* 1560; *polygon* 1560;  *pentagon* 1570; *octagon* 1594; *trigon* 1600 (basically all around the same time)
It looks like we adopted a neat Latin naming convention as we found interest and practical use for more figures with an increasing numbers of sides:

> **-gon, comb. form**
>
> *1652   *News from Lowe Countreys* 2   For 'tis not..**Trigonall**, or Pentagonall, Or any of the **Gones** at all* OED
>
> **Etymology**:  < classical Latin -gōnon (in e.g. octagōnon octagon n.), -gōnum (in e.g. trigōnum trigon n.) ...
>
> Compare French -*gone*.

It's unreasonable to think we'd rename our three- and four-sided shapes—triangles, quadrangles, squares, and rectangles. We just "gone" off after that: new shapes need new names.

The OED has this telling early citation for **hexagon**:

> 1570   H. Billingsley tr. **Euclid** Elements Geom. iv. f. 124   We
> may in a **Hexagon** geuen either describe or circumscribe a circle.

I think  architectural and scientific interest in geometry (and Euclid in particular) played a role in adopting *-gone*.

An interesting early -angle "exception" is the five-pointed star, a *pentangle* (1390):

> A pentagram; a talisman or magical symbol in the shape of or inscribed
> with a pentagram OED

In other words, a pentangle isn't a pentagon.

Comment: My mistake-- edited. The -gon comes from the greek for *knee*, so also *angle.*

Comment: Jolly good. and remembering that the only point here is the difference, how does that address the difference between three- and four- or five- or more-angled figures.

Comment: Thanks and how does that address the Question? I was not asking about what the difference is, but why there is a difference…

If I failed to make that clear, where did I go wrong?

I didn't bother to contrast pentagram to pentagon because here, that difference seems irrelevant; In other words, a pentangle is a pentagon when the shape is what matters.

If the reason for drawing that shape is what matters, you're moving outside language and into philosophy…